# Approximation of multivariate functions by a polynomial

Tags: reference-request, approximation-theory, orthogonal-polynomials, multivalued-functions

Is there any reference about approximating multivariate functions  with polynomials ?

I search on google, but I fail to find  my goal. Does any one come across a book detailed in this manner.

Comment: [Taylor polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) still work, and there are [interpolating polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation) as well. What suits you best is difficult to say without knowing more about what you want to use it for.

Comment: There exist very many ways to do that. What does your data look like and what limits do you have on the computational devices?

Comment: @mathreadler I am studying a general case, so  for that i am asking for a reference that may summarize  these " very many ways"  to have a good idea about the different methods exist in different configurations

Comment: You can try and fit a set of discrete points measured on your function to a multivariate polynomial with linear least squares. It is probably the most straight forward approach. You can also measure partial derivatives or gradients of different orders and force your polynomial to fit those. It will be relatively nice to do since differentiation is linear and the monomials are closed under differentiation so it will still work with a big linear least squares problem.